# Grouping activities in time sequence using SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am analysing a period of time with breaks in it.  I know that the period starts on any given day at 00:00 and ends just before 00:15.  I further have a table with this information:

```
create table #Activities (Description varchar(25),[Start] Time2(7),[End] time2(7))
insert into #Activities ([Description],[Start],[End]) select 'Break 1','00:04','00:07:59.9999999'
insert into #Activities ([Description],[Start],[End]) select 'Break 1','00:12','00:14:59.9999999'
```

I am looking for an output that looks like this
[image]

What is the best way to achieve this without using a cursor?

Answer (score 0):

using `lag()` in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (a subquery would work just as well too).:

```
;with cte as (
  select Description, Start,[End]
    , lag([end]) over (order by start)as PrevEnd
  from #activities
)
select Description, Start,[End]
from #activities
union all
select 
    'Not a break '+convert(varchar(10),row_number() over(order by start))
  , isnull(dateadd(nanosecond,100,PrevEnd),'00:00')
  , dateadd(nanosecond,-100,Start)
from cte
where isnull(dateadd(nanosecond,100,PrevEnd),'00:00')<>Start
order by start,[End]
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DQI53300

returns:

```
+---------------+----------+------------------+
|  Description  |  Start   |       End        |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
| Not a break 1 | 00:00:00 | 00:03:59.9999999 |
| Break 1       | 00:04:00 | 00:07:59.9999999 |
| Not a break 2 | 00:08:00 | 00:11:59.9999999 |
| Break 1       | 00:12:00 | 00:14:59.9999999 |
+---------------+----------+------------------+
```